# What is the role of Glommer?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

In *Don't Starve: Reign of Giants*, you can pick a Glommer Flower from Glommer's Statue during a Full Moon to make Glommer follow you.

What's the point? Is it for cuteness's sake, or is there any strategic advantage whatsoever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Don't Starve wiki](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Glommer):

> When tamed, Glommer provides a [Sanity](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Sanity) aura of +6.25/min, making it useful in countering the nighttime sanity drain of -5/min. It will also drop [Glommer's Goop](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Glommer%27s_Goop) once every 2–4 days.

As for Glommer's Goop:

> Other than its use as fuel for a Fire (with a fuel value equivalent to Boards), it can be eaten, providing 40 health and around 9 hunger, but decreasing sanity by 50.

When killed, it drops [Glommer's Wings](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Glommer%27s_Wings):

> Glommer's Wings are a nonperishable item dropped by Glommer used to craft the Old Bell. It is renewable as the player can obtain one each Full Moon by killing Glommer.
>
> The Wings can also be used as fuel for fires or the Ice Flingomatic.

But note that killing Glommer will immediately summon [Krampus](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Krampus).